# Using MATLAB, assign maximum values of each sub data set to the original data set (replace the data column with maximum if each sub data set)

Tags: matlab

Using MATLAB, I have a dataset (dune_h_data.txt) with x coordinates (1st column) and dune heights (2nd column). For same x coordinate (subset), there are several dune heights. I want to replace the dune height column or add a third column using the maximum value of each subset of dune heights for each x coordinate of that subset. 
I created a script using MATLAB. I found the maximum dune height for each subset where x coordinates are unique. I used following commands.

```
[lines, ~, subs] = unique(x_co1);
Max_h = accumarray(subs, h, [], @max);
```

I could not assign these maximum dune height values to each coordinate corresponding to every subset. Please see my script. The expected results are shown in a sample data set "Max_dune_h (expected output).txt".

```
dune_h_data.txt
x_co1   
-21292.90039
-21292.90039
-21292.90039
-21292.90039
-21242.90039
-21242.90039
-21242.90039
-21242.90039
-21242.90039
-21192.90039
-21192.90039
-21192.90039
-21192.90039
-21192.90039
-21142.90039
-21142.90039
-21142.90039
-21142.90039
-21092.90039
-21092.90039
```

the corresponding column of dune_heights

```
7.17153931
-7.93923998
-8.47749615
-8.5275507
8.57088375
-7.11603069
-7.87911987
-8.24691391
-8.5357933
8.86667347
0.86596704
-7.5994606
-8.20367718
-8.51330662
4.77929735
0.34045759
-8.10092926
-8.2374649
4.20417213
-7.31984854
```

Expected maximum dune height column corresponding to the x coordinates

```
7.17153931
7.17153931
7.17153931
7.17153931
8.57088375
8.57088375
8.57088375
8.57088375
8.57088375
8.86667347
8.86667347
8.86667347
8.86667347
8.86667347
4.77929735
4.77929735
4.77929735
4.77929735
4.20417213
4.20417213
```

I try to write resulting maximum dune height and the average value of the x coordinates. Then tried to make a loop with if condition. But I got only 0 values for the expected results. As I am not very much familiar with MATLAB SCRIPTING, I believe there should be a simple approach to this.

I can attach the sample dataset but I do not how to do it here.

```
 %%% average of dune height for each x coordinates

 load dune_h_data.txt

 x_co1=dune_h_data(:,1);
 h=dune_h_data(:,2);

 x_co1_int=round(x_co1);

 fileID18 = fopen('x_co1_int.txt','w');
 fprintf(fileID18,'%6.0f\r\n',x_co1_int);
 fclose(fileID18);

 [lines, ~, subs] = unique(x_co1);

 Max_h = accumarray(subs, h, [], @max);

 x_co_avg = accumarray(subs, x_co1, [], @mean);


 fileID15 = fopen('Max_h.txt','w');
 fprintf(fileID15,'%6.5f\r\n',Max_h);
 fclose(fileID15);

 fileID16 = fopen('x_co_avg.txt','w');
 fprintf(fileID16,'%6.0f\r\n',x_co_avg);
 fclose(fileID16);

 x_co_avg_Max_h=[x_co_avg Max_h];

 dune_h=zeros(size(x_co1));

 m1=1:length(Max_h);
 j1=1:length(x_co_avg);

    for k1=1:length(x_co1_int)

        x_co1v=x_co1_int(k1);

        for j1=1:length(x_co_avg)

            x_co_avg_u=x_co_avg(j1);

             if x_co1v(k1) == x_co_avg_u(j1)

                m1=j1;      
             dune_h(k1)=Max_h(m1);

             end

        end 

        fileID17 = fopen('dune_h.txt','w');
        fprintf(fileID17,'%6.7f\r\n',dune_h);
        fclose(fileID17); 

     end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt was on the right track. Using your data,

```
[lines, ~, subs] = unique(x_co1);
Max_h = accumarray(subs, h, [], @max);
```

gives you a `Max_h` of:

```
Max_h =
   7.1715
   8.5709
   8.8667
   4.7793
   4.2042
```

Now all that's left is to create a new vector giving the corresponding max height for each subscript in `subs`:

```
Max_subs_h = Max_h(subs);
Max_subs_h =
   7.1715
   7.1715
   7.1715
   7.1715
   8.5709
   8.5709
   8.5709
   8.5709
   8.5709
   8.8667
   8.8667
   8.8667
   8.8667
   8.8667
   4.7793
   4.7793
   4.7793
   4.7793
   4.2042
   4.2042
```

Comment: Dear beaker, thank you very much for your answer. It worked very nicely. I also like to thank you for reformating my question. Thank you so much for your time. Ruwan